# Google calendar api JS doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, google-calendar-api

I use code from official tutorial:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Google Calendar API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
</head>
<body>
<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize-button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout-button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>
<pre id="content"></pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    var CLIENT_ID = '930775442242-5dutsv4pa4ibr23c650rcs4upo3v7qad.apps.googleusercontent.com';
    // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
    var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest"];
    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly";
    var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout-button');
    /**
     *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
     */
    function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }
    /**
     *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
     *  listeners.
     */
    function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
            discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
            clientId: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);
            // Handle the initial sign-in state.
            updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
            authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
            signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
    }

    /**
     *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
     *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
     */
    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
            listUpcomingEvents();
        } else {
            authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
            signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
    }
    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
    }
    /**
     * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
     * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
     *
     * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
     */
    function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
    }

    /**
     * Print the summary and start datetime/date of the next ten events in
     * the authorized user's calendar. If no events are found an
     * appropriate message is printed.
     */
    function listUpcomingEvents() {
        gapi.client.calendar.events.list({
            'calendarId': 'primary',
            'timeMin': (new Date()).toISOString(),
            'showDeleted': false,
            'singleEvents': true,
            'maxResults': 10,
            'orderBy': 'startTime'
        }).then(function(response) {
            var events = response.result.items;
            appendPre('Upcoming events:');

            if (events.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                    var event = events[i];
                    var when = event.start.dateTime;
                    if (!when) {
                        when = event.start.date;
                    }
                    appendPre(event.summary + ' (' + when + ')')
                }
            } else {
                appendPre('No upcoming events found.');
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Therea are two buttons for sign in and for sign out.
Problem: this code doesn't work in firefox (when I click auth button, choose google account then nothing happens) and in chrome (I cant logout).
Maybe there is any error in this code?
How can I solve this problem?
In my console there are not any errors.
Thanks,

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an error message or problem description. Use your browser's developer tools to debug your code and discover any error messages, unexpected behaviours etc which are occurring, and then update your question with more detailed information. The tools are more than just the console - since this is all supposed to be communicating with google, watching the network tab and seeing what requests are (or are not) made should be instructive at the very least.

Comment: thanks, but I dont see any problems in console and other tools
I think maybe api needs api key, but dont know where I must set it

Comment: if it's not in the demo code then it's unlikely that you need it, assuming you're carrying out the same actions. It's hard to believe there are no errors at all, unless the code just simply isn't executing. If there were really such obvious bugs in the service, then no-one would use it. What changes have you made to the original demo? Your own client ID etc I guess, anything else?

Answer (score 0):

For the signing-out process try using GoogleAuth.disconnect(); to revoke the token which was mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#tokenrevoke).

The calendar API sample is working as intended on my end. Make sure it's enabled in your Google Dev console and the localhost ports are indicated in your clientID